# Gremlin Server : Getting ClosedChannelException for some cases . How to resolve this exception?

Tags: java, exception, gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I am using withRemote to connect my java application to gremlin server. I'm running gremlin query for my inputs . But for some inputs I'm facing this issue :

```
[junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    [junit]     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:77)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:130)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.fill(Traversal.java:179)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.toList(Traversal.java:117)
    [junit]     at com.lineage.scripts.neptune.client.NeptuneQueryClientImpl.getVertexList(NeptuneQueryClientImpl.java:92)
    [junit]     at com.lineage.scripts.neptune.client.NeptuneQueryClientImpl.getUpstreamTable(NeptuneQueryClientImpl.java:70)
    [junit]     at com.lineage.scripts.neptune.client.NeptuneQueryClientImpl.getUpstreamTableDepthForVertexId(NeptuneQueryClientImpl.java:23)
    [junit]     at com.lineage.scripts.djs.intermediatetable.InterMediateTableForProvider.getUpstreamForATable(InterMediateTableForProvider.java:150)
    [junit]     at com.lineage.scripts.djs.intermediatetable.InterMediateTableForProvider.lambda$null$1(InterMediateTableForProvider.java:105)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [junit]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:749)
    [junit] Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:958)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:866)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1379)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:56)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1102)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1149)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1073)
    [junit]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    [junit]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    [junit]     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    [junit]     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    [junit]     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    [junit]     ... 1 more
```

I looked in the gremlin docs and few stackoverflow articles and changed the configuration as well.

'''

```
            maxWaitForConnection(3000).
            reconnectInterval(1000).
            maxWaitForSessionClose(120000).
            maxContentLength(65536000).
            keepAliveInterval(180000).
            maxConnectionPoolSize(500)
```

I'm still not able to figure out why I'm getting exception here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information to describe the circumstances for how/when you get this error. It would be also good to know if that error is occurring on the client or the server. If it's the client, I'd also be curious what your server logs look like and if there is any further errors or warnings there.

Comment: @stephenmallette   I have 2000 elements for which I have to fetch information using gremlin query . I implemented multithreading for scaling . But for some elements , it was throwing the above error . I looked in the docs as well , but could'nt resolve it.

Comment: `ClosedChannelException` means that *you* closed the channel and then continued to use it.

Comment: Do you get the exception without the multi-threading? Are there server logs to consider?

Comment: @user207421 Yes I looked for cause of that exception . I also looked for neptune and gremlin docs for this IllegalStateException . But could'nt resolve it.

Comment: @stephenmallette I can't really say about before multithreading . Because it's was a part of a big project.

Comment: The idea is to look for premature closures and continuances to use the closed channel. Not to just look for the exception.

Comment: @stephenmallette Mutlithreading was not the issue. Consider, my case as graph traversal using bfs , where I have to fetch details of all node of every level. I mean, For every level, it is doing gremlin query to get details of nodes. So , for like big graph i.e more levels with more nodes . Somehow for them this error occurs after fetching certain levels. But when i give them again new connections. It executes without throwing any error. Please help me here .